# How do you initialize a static templated container?

Tags: c++, templates, class, static, nested

I'm trying to figure out the correct way of initializing a static container variable whose template value is a private inner class. Here's a toy example

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class myType>
class Foo {
private:
    class Bar {
        int x;
    };

    static vector<Bar*> bars;
};

template <class myType>
vector<Bar*> Foo<myType>::bars; // error C2065: 'Bar' : undeclared identifier
```

I've also tried

```
...

template <class myType>
vector<Foo<myType>::Bar*> Foo<myType>::bars; // error C2059: syntax error : '>'
```

It works if `class Bar` is declared outside of `class Foo` but from a design standpoint this is an ugly solution.  Any suggestions?

FYI, everything is declared in a .h file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <class myType>
vector<typename Foo<myType>::Bar*> Foo<myType>::bars;
```

Comment: Beat me by 4secs! `:+1` from me.

Comment: i always got beaten by large margin. :(

Comment: Yup, beat me too.  The rule is, use keyword `typename` before A::B whenever it's supposed to be a type and expression A involves a template parameter.

Comment: It works.  Thanks!  You guys are awesome.  Now to google `typename` :-)

Comment: If anyone wants a good explanation of why C++ requires `typename` under the circumstances described by _aschepler_, see this site http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

Answer (score -1):

`vector<Foo::Bar*> Foo<myType>::bars;` ... note the `Foo::`

Comment: @dgnorton: Have you tried compiling it? It fails on `gcc`. `Foo` needs to be qualified with the type parameter among other things.

Comment: @Richard, on VS 2008 yes (no warnings)...on my way to compiling on gcc

Comment: @Richard, I'm not worried about rep.  I'll leave my wrong answer here for everyone else's education.  Still working on the gcc test.

Comment: @Richard, gcc didn't like it at all.  Just leave it down voted (as it deserves to be) so that someone else using VS 2008 (VC9 compiler) might benefit.